# `md(4)` command turns screen on when it starts or stops checking the arrays

Tags: power-management, kubuntu, md

Every time `md` (or is it `mdcheck`?) performs a RAID check or pauses/continues it, the screen of my device turns on.

These are the relevant `syslog` entries, the screen turned on at 6:15:

```
Jul  4 06:11:25 machine systemd[1]: Finished Daily apt download activities.
Jul  4 06:15:20 machine systemd[1]: Starting MD array scrubbing - continuation...
Jul  4 06:15:20 machine root: mdcheck continue checking /dev/md2 from 17114041344
Jul  4 06:15:20 machine kernel: [639971.327078] md: data-check of RAID array md2
Jul  4 06:15:24 machine rtkit-daemon[1997]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Jul  4 06:15:24 machine rtkit-daemon[1997]: Successfully made thread 225575 of process 1996 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Jul  4 06:15:24 machine rtkit-daemon[1997]: Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Jul  4 06:17:01 machine CRON[225614]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

The RAID check takes a long time, maybe around 20 hours, so it is automatically split into multiple segments of a few hours each over the span of a couple of days. During this time, the screen always turns on as soon as the check begins/pauses/continues/ends.

The only sensible cause suggested to me by a chatbot was that it might be Notification Pop-Ups, but when I check the notification history from "Status and Notifications" in the systray, it is empty.

I usually turn the screen off by executing `DISPLAY=:0.0 xset dpms force off`

How can I avoid this from happening?

---

**Update:**

Further analysis has shown that

```
echo check | sudo tee /sys/block/md1/md/sync_action
echo idle  | sudo tee /sys/block/md1/md/sync_action
```

both turn on the monitor.

`mdcheck` which is triggered by `systemd` does write these flags into `/sys/block/mdX/md/sync_action` which then causes the issue.

**Update 2:**

I just created a new RAID array, and when issuing the command

```
sudo mdadm
   --create /dev/md3 
   --level=1 
   --raid-devices=2 
   /dev/by-id/wwn-0x500a0aaaaaaaaaaa-part1 
   /dev/by-id/wwn-0x500a0bbbbbbbbbbb-part1
```

and answering `yes` to `Continue creating array?`, as soon as I hit enter, it turned on the screen.

These were the syslog entries:

```
Jul 15 22:44:05 machine systemd-udevd[17072]: md3: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/md3' failed with exit code 1.
Jul 15 22:44:05 machine kernel: [17061.713250] md/raid1:md3: not clean -- starting background reconstruction
Jul 15 22:44:05 machine kernel: [17061.713253] md/raid1:md3: active with 2 out of 2 mirrors
Jul 15 22:44:05 machine udisksd[1921]: The function 'bd_md_examine' called, but not implemented!
Jul 15 22:44:05 machine udisksd[1921]: The function 'bd_md_examine' called, but not implemented!
Jul 15 22:44:05 machine kernel: [17061.717282] md3: detected capacity change from 0 to 7813574656
Jul 15 22:44:05 machine kernel: [17061.717426] md: resync of RAID array md3
Jul 15 22:44:10 machine rtkit-daemon[2680]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Jul 15 22:44:10 machine rtkit-daemon[2680]: Successfully made thread 17135 of process 2679 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Jul 15 22:44:10 machine rtkit-daemon[2680]: Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
```

**Update 3:**

After filling the new array with data and then issuing `echo check > /sys/block/md3/md/sync_action`, the screen turned on again.

These are the syslog entries:

```
Jul 16 18:52:23 machine kernel: [89559.476770] md: data-check of RAID array md3
Jul 16 18:52:28 machine rtkit-daemon[2680]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Jul 16 18:52:28 machine rtkit-daemon[2680]: Successfully made thread 85585 of process 2679 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Jul 16 18:52:28 machine rtkit-daemon[2680]: Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
```

It is something `md` which is causing this, might as well be related to `rtkit-daemon` doing some stuff.

Comment: `echo ... sudo tee ...` causes one copy of the echoed text to pass to standard output. Is `mdcheck` configured to output to console when triggered by `systemd`? If you change the triggering commands to the form `echo ... | sudo tee ... >/dev/null`, will they still turn on the monitor?

Comment: @telcoM wouldn't that mean that `echo check | sudo tee /dev/null` would also turn on the monitor? It didn't. I won't test your suggestion right now because I don't want to trigger a new check, but I triggered one about two hours ago and then let it run until it finished, which made the file automatically change to `idle` and the screen went on again when this happened. It's something internal to the device, assuming `/sys/block/mdX/md/sync_action` is a device.

Comment: @telcoM I now issued a `echo check > /sys/block/md3/md/sync_action` and this turned on the screen, I also added an update to the question, mentioning that this also happens with `mdamd --create`